# Swagger ui is unable to load the json specification file in server

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui

I have swagger ui and a open api specification 3.0 json file. When I run the index.html file from my local iis it is showing the swagger ui with the documentation. But when I run it from the server it is throwing ***can't read the file*** error. The index.html has the relative path of the json file.

```
window.onload = function() {

  // Build a system
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        urls: [
            {
                url: "../OASDoc/v1_apidoc.json",
                name:"Version 1.0.0"
            }
              ],
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })

  window.ui = ui
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the full URL you use to access Swagger UI and the full URL of your `v1_apidoc.json` file?

Comment: full url is https://xxxx.xxxx.com/appFolder/OASDoc/v1_apidoc.json. I tried the full url in the index.html. Also when I tried to access the json file url in the browser directly it was throwing error 404 file or directory not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to access the api JSON doc file from the URL (xxxx.xxxx.com/appFolder/OASDoc/v1_apidoc.json) and it was not accessible, but all other files like a text file were accessible. I figured it was because of the file extension.
To override the restriction I added the below mime type mapping to the web.config file and it worked.

```
<system.webServer> 
  <staticContent> 
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/> 
  </staticContent> 
</system.webServer>
```